# Ticker having trouble

Tags: java, javascript, html, css

i have made a ticker, and as you can see, the first line (Grand opening of Elite Gamer) is perfect and green. Keep watching until it loops back. The text turns black, and i can not click on the link. does someone have a solution? http://jsfiddle.net/Hunter4854/AtKtR/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the li around your first entry and it will work the way you designed it to.

[New Fiddle With Fix](http://jsfiddle.net/c4g2s/)

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="link" style="padding-top:2px; text-decoration:none;     color: #00B700; font-weight: bold; text-shadow: #00ff00 0px 0px 1px; ">Grand Opening of Elite Gamer</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is incomplete or misleading and possibly dangerous. An `<ol>` element must not have any other content but `<li>` elements, so the `<a>`s are not allowed in there. See, for example, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/ol) for the reference. I have now updated my own answer to contain the correct solution.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated answer:** OK, [here's a working version of your ticker](http://jsfiddle.net/KFFdg/). The problem was that you were mixing `<li>` and `<a>` elements carelessly. I have now removed the `<ol>` element entirely and replaced it with a simple `<div>` that contains those `<a>` elements. I also cleaned up your CSS code so that no styling instructions are mixed with the HTML code. Then I changed that one if-statement into this:

```
if (list.find('.link').length > 1 )
```

as previously it was finding the `li` elements which didn't work that well.

---

**My initial answer:** For one, you had `<a>` elements around the `<li>` elements, which is illegal. The `<a>`s should be inside the `<li>`s. [I've created you a new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vUCKQ/) where I have also moved the JS code into the JS window and the CSS code into the CSS window for readability.

Looking at the DOM with Chrome's Inspect element feature it seems to me that the `<a>` elements are being removed from the DOM, so obviously they cannot be clicked afterwards. Do something about that and it should be pretty much perfect quite soon. :)

Comment: when i hover over the links, the pointer hand does not come up.

Comment: The point is to have it be able to click.

Comment: @HunterMitchell I just tried to point you into the correct direction by pointing out your mistakes, but I've now edited the answer to contain the correct solution. Please accept my answer.